# Solving recurrence relation with exponential generating function

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Attempting to solve the recurrence relation $$a_{n+1} = 2na_n+a_n+2$$

with $a_0=1$ (solution in summation form, closed form not necessary)

Let $E(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$, and multiply each time in the relation by $ \frac{x^n}{n!}$ and take the sum.

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(2n+1)a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}+2\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

notice that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n!}=E'(x)$, and $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$. But I'm not sure what I can do with the middle sum, differentiating/integrating it doesn't seem to help, nor does substitutions like $m=2n+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The middle term is $2 \sum a_n\frac {x^{n}} {(n-1)!}+E(x)$. You can write this as $2x\sum a_{n+1}\frac {x^{n}} {n!} +E(x)=2xE'(x)+E(x)$

Comment: thanks for the hint, I've gotten the expression now to $(1-2x)E'(x)=E(x)+2e^x$ which is the same as $E(x)=(1-2x)E'(x)-2e^x$. I suppose I can write it as $E(x)=(1-2x)\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n!}-2e^x$, but I don't think I can simplify it further can I?

Comment: You already know that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n!}=E'(x)$ Now you have  a  differential equation to solve.